# Convert octal to hexadecimal

Tags: binary-operations

My teacher told us it was possible to convert octal(105A) to hexadecimal: it would be equal to hex(10510).

But I though it was impossible to have a number greater than the base, and A > 8 (I think, so correct me if I'm wrong).

I know that hex(A) = decimal(10) = octal(12) but I'm really confused.

TL;DR:
Is this possible to have octal(105A) = hex(10510) ?

Comment: You make a mistake in hex(A) to octal conversion – the octal result is 12, not 21.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected my mistake!

Comment: The hex should be shorter than the octal as well because the leading digit in your octal is $8^3$ while in the hex it is $16^4,$ much greater.  It is also false that octal (10510) equals hex(105A).  In fact hex(105A)=octal (10132)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations. Makes things much clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have such input. Octal digits are 0 through 7, A is not allowed.